# Slow performance Openlayers in UI5 when too many features

Tags: performance, controller, sapui5, openlayers

```js
    sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/m/Label",
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
    "zpr/analyse/ZPR-Analyse/controller/fragments/Header.controller",
    "sap/ui/util/Storage"
], function(Controller, JSONModel, Label, Filter, Header) {
    "use strict";

    // Define arrays which hold data and map
    var aInfo = [];
    var assets = [];
    var oLocations, map;
    var aLocations = [];

    // Define all the layers for both total journey and last location
    var groupTotalJourneyLayers, groupTotalJourneyLines, groupClusterLayers;

    // Define the variables we need to keep track of all the sources
    var counter = 0;
    var sourceTotalLocations = [];

    var aLayers = [];
    var features = [];
    var allLayers = [];
    var allClusters = [];
    var marker = new ol.Feature();
    var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector();

    return Controller.extend("zpr.analyse.ZPR-Analyse.controller.Map", {
        Header: new Header(this),

        onInit: function() {
            this._oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
            this._oRouter.getRoute("RouteMap").attachMatched(this.initialize, this);
        },

        initialize: function (oEvent) {
            var that = this;

            that.resetEverything();

            // Set weburl
            var weburl = "https://eks.ordina-jworks.io/zpr-bff/assets/export";

            // Get data from asset
            // We pass the authentication required for the endpoint along with the call
            $.ajax({
                url: weburl,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                //  headers:{
                //  Authorization:"Bearer "+authenticationToken 
                //  },
                success: function (dataj) {
                    //assets = dataj;

                    //Here we remove all duplicated keys in the assets/export api using JQuery
                    $.each(dataj, function(key, value) {
                    var exists = false;
                    $.each(assets, function(k, val2) {
                      if(value.id === val2.id) {exists = true;}
                    });
                    if(exists === false && value.id !== "") { assets.push(value); }
                    });

                    //Selects are filled with data      
                    that.feedData();

                    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                    oModel.setData(assets);
                    that.getView().setModel(oModel);

                    //Keys are assigned to selects
                    that.aKeys = [
                        "Batch", "Type", "Color", "Location"
                    ];
                    that.oSelectName = that.getSelect("slBatch");
                    that.oSelectType = that.getSelect("slType");
                    that.oSelectColor = that.getSelect("slColor");
                    that.oSelectLocation = that.getSelect("slLocation");
                    that.oDateBegin = that.getSelect("dBeginDate");
                    that.oDateEnd = that.getSelect("dEndDate");

                    var oFB = that.getView().byId("filterbar");
                    if (oFB) {
                        oFB.variantsInitialized();
                    }


                },
                error: function (errorstatus, statusText) {
                    // If the user is unauthorized we redirect him back to the login page
                }
            }).done(function () {
            });
        },

        onExit: function() {
            this.aKeys = [];
            this.aFilters = [];
            this.oModel = null;
        },
        onToggleHeader: function() {
            this.getPage().setHeaderExpanded(!this.getPage().getHeaderExpanded());
        },

        onSelectChange: function() {
            var aCurrentFilterValues = [];
            var busyDialog = this.getView().byId("BusyDialog");

            aCurrentFilterValues.push(this.getSelectedItemText(this.oSelectName));
            aCurrentFilterValues.push(this.getSelectedItemText(this.oSelectType));
            aCurrentFilterValues.push(this.getSelectedItemText(this.oSelectColor));
            aCurrentFilterValues.push(this.getSelectedItemText(this.oSelectLocation));
            aCurrentFilterValues.push((this.oDateBegin).getValue());
            aCurrentFilterValues.push((this.oDateEnd).getValue());


            busyDialog.setVisible(true);
            busyDialog.open();
            this.filterMap(aCurrentFilterValues);
            busyDialog.close();
            busyDialog.setVisible(false);    
        },

        filterMap: function(aCurrentFilterValues) {

            //this.resetEverything();

            //If type filter is applied following code will filter data
            if(aCurrentFilterValues[1] !== "TYPE0"){
                var assetJourneysLength;

                if(aCurrentFilterValues[1] === "TYPE1"){
                    for(var x in assets){
                        if(assets[x].type === "CONNECTED"){
                            assetJourneysLength = assets[x].assetJourneys.length;
                            aInfo.push(assets[x].physicalId);
                            oLocations.push(assets[x].assetJourneys[assetJourneysLength - 1].lastLocationData);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    for(var y in assets){
                        if(assets[y].type === "UNCONNECTED"){
                            assetJourneysLength = assets[y].assetJourneys.length;
                            aInfo.push(assets[y].physicalId);
                            oLocations.push(assets[y].assetJourneys[assetJourneysLength - 1].lastLocationData);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Following filter sets an interval between two dates which shows the assets, which changed location between interval.
            if(aCurrentFilterValues[4] !== "" && aCurrentFilterValues[5] !== ""){
                for(var a in assets){
                    for (var b in assets[a].assetJourneys){
                        for (var c in assets[a].assetJourneys[b].locations){
                            var timestamp = assets[a].assetJourneys[b].locations[c].timestamp;
                            if(timestamp.substring(0, timestamp.indexOf("T")) >= this.oDateBegin.getValue() && timestamp .substring(0, timestamp.indexOf("T")) <= this.oDateEnd.getValue()){
                                aInfo.push(assets[a].physicalId);
                                oLocations.push(assets[a].assetJourneys[b].locations[c]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else if(aCurrentFilterValues[4] !== "" || aCurrentFilterValues[5] !== ""){
                return ; 
            }

            // //If end date filter is applied following code will filter data
            // if(aCurrentFilterValues[5] !== ""  && aCurrentFilterValues[4] !== ""){
            //  for(var d in assets){
            //      for (var e in assets[d].assetJourneys){
            //          for (var f in assets[d].assetJourneys[e].locations){
            //              var timestamp2 = assets[d].assetJourneys[e].locations[f].timestamp;
            //              if(timestamp2.substring(0, timestamp2.indexOf("T")) <= this.oDateEnd.getValue() && timestamp2.substring(0, timestamp2.indexOf("T")) >= this.oDateBegin.getValue()){
            //                  aInfo.push(assets[d].physicalId);
            //                  oLocations.push(assets[d].assetJourneys[e].locations[f]);
            //              }
            //          }
            //      }
            //  }
            // }
            this.createLastLocations();
            this.showTotalJourney();
        },

        createLastLocations: function() {
            // Reset locations array array
            aLocations.length = 0;

            features = oLocations.map(function(location){

                marker = new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
                        ol.proj.fromLonLat([location.longitude, location.latitude])
                    )
                });

                marker.set('info', aInfo[counter]);
                counter++;
                marker.set('timestamp', location.timestamp);

                return marker;
            });

            oLocations.forEach(function(location) {
                // Fill an array with solely the converted longitude and latitude
                aLocations.push(
                    ol.proj.fromLonLat([location.longitude, location.latitude])
                );

                // Create a marker (= feature) which references to the location of the asset
                 marker = new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
                        ol.proj.fromLonLat([location.longitude, location.latitude])
                    )
                });

                // Change the style of the marker and use a custom icon
                marker.setStyle( new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Circle({
                        radius: 15,
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#E6600D'}),
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: [255,0,0], width: 2
                        })
                    })
                }));

                // Create a vector based on the features
                var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                    features: features
                });

                var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
                    distance: 30,
                    source: vectorSource
                });

                var styleCache = {};
                clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
                  source: clusterSource,
                  style: function(feature) {
                    var size = feature.get("features").length;
                    var style = styleCache[size];
                    if (!style) {
                      style = new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({
                          radius: 15,
                          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: "#fff"
                          }),
                          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: "#E6600D"
                          })
                        }),
                        text: new ol.style.Text({
                          text: size.toString(),
                          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: "#fff"
                          })
                        })
                      });
                      styleCache[size] = style;
                    }
                    return style;
                  }
                });

                // Create layer based on a vector       
                var markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                    source: vectorSource
                });

                allClusters.push(clusters);
                allLayers.push(markerVectorLayer);
                allLayers.push(clusters);
                aLayers.push(markerVectorLayer);
                sourceTotalLocations.push(vectorSource);
            });

            if(aLocations.length > 0) {
                groupTotalJourneyLayers = new ol.layer.Group({
                    layers: aLayers,
                    name: 'totalJourneysGroup'

                });

                groupClusterLayers = new ol.layer.Group({
                    layers: allClusters,
                    name: 'totalClusters'

                });
            }
        },

        showTotalJourney: function() {
            var that = this;

            // Add both layers that belong to the total journey to the map
            map.addLayer(groupTotalJourneyLayers);
            map.addLayer(groupClusterLayers);

            // Reset the center of the map
            if(oLocations.length > 0){
                that.setMapCenter(oLocations[(oLocations.length - 1)].longitude, oLocations[(oLocations.length - 1)].latitude);
            }
        },

        getFilters: function(aCurrentFilterValues) {
            this.aFilters = [];

            this.aFilters = this.aKeys.map(function(sCriteria, i) {
                return new Filter(sCriteria, sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, aCurrentFilterValues[i]);
            });

            return this.aFilters;
        },

        getFormattedSummaryText: function(aFilterCriterias) {
            if (aFilterCriterias.length > 0) {
                return "Filtered By (" + aFilterCriterias.length + "): " + aFilterCriterias.join(", ");
            } else {
                return "Filtered by None";
            }
        },

        getMap: function() {
            return this.getView().byId("map_canvas");
        },

        getSelect: function(sId) {
            return this.getView().byId(sId);
        },
        getSelectedItemText: function(oSelect) {
            return oSelect.getSelectedItem() ? oSelect.getSelectedItem().getKey() : "";
        },
        getPage: function() {
            return this.getView().byId("dynamicPageId");
        },
        getPageTitle: function() {
            return this.getPage().getTitle();
        },

        onAfterRendering: function () {
            var that = this;
            if (!that.initialized) {
                that.initialized = true;

                // Set OpenLayers map
                map = new ol.Map({
                    target: that.getView().byId("map_canvas").getDomRef(),
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                    ],
                    //overlays: [overlay],  // OVERLAY
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.357582, 51.198185]),
                        zoom: 10
                    })
                });
            }

            // Function which will show the info of the layer that has been clicked on
            map.on("singleclick", function(e) {
                map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (feature, layer) {

                    if(allLayers.includes(layer)) {
                        // Only show a messagebox when a marker has been clicked on, info is a unique property given by the marker layers
                        if (feature.get('info'))
                        {
                            // Transform coördinates to a longitude & latitude array
                            var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

                            // Show the converted longitude and latitude as well as the info
                            that.getView().byId('txtLocationInfo').setText(ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS([lonlat[0], lonlat[1]]));
                            that.getView().byId('txtAssetInfo').setText("Physical ID: " + feature.get('info'));
                            that.getView().byId('txtTimestamp').setText("Timestamp: " + feature.get('timestamp'));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        },

        setMapCenter: function(longitude, latitude) {
            // Set center a new center on the map 
            map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([longitude, latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
        },

        feedData: function(){
            var that = this;
            //This is created to gain Batch in filters
            var oSlBatchJSON = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var Batch = {
                    Batch : [{
                        name : "CHOOSE A BATCH",
                        key  : "BATCH0"
                    },{
                        name : "BATCH 1",
                        key  : "BATCH1"
                    },{
                        name : "BATCH 2",
                        key  : "BATCH2"
                    },{
                        name : "BATCH 3",
                        key  : "BATCH3"
                    },{
                        name : "BATCH 4",
                        key  : "BATCH4"
                    },{
                        name : "BATCH 5",
                        key  : "BATCH5"
                    },{
                        name : "BATCH 6",
                        key  : "BATCH6"
                    }]
            };
            oSlBatchJSON.setData(Batch);
            that.getView().byId("slBatch").setModel(oSlBatchJSON);

            //This is created to gain Type in filters
            var oSlTypeJSON = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var Type = {
                    Type : [{
                        name : "CHOOSE A TYPE",
                        key  : "TYPE0"
                    },{
                        name : "CONNECTED",
                        key  : "TYPE1"
                    },{
                        name : "UNCONNECTED",
                        key  : "TYPE2"
                    }]
            };
            oSlTypeJSON.setData(Type);
            that.getView().byId("slType").setModel(oSlTypeJSON);

            //This is created to gain Color in filters
            var oSlColorJSON = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var Color = {
                    Color : [{
                        name : "CHOOSE A COLOR",
                        key  : "COLOR0"
                    },{
                        name : "RED",
                        key  : "COLOR1"
                    },{
                        name : "BLUE",
                        key  : "COLOR2"
                    },{
                        name : "BLACK",
                        key  : "COLOR3"
                    }]
            };
            oSlColorJSON.setData(Color);
            that.getView().byId("slColor").setModel(oSlColorJSON);

            //This is created to gain Location in filters
            var oSlLocationJSON = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var Location = {
                    Location : [{
                        name : "CHOOSE A LOCATION",
                        key  : "LOC0"
                    },{
                        name : "MELLE",
                        key  : "LOC1"
                    },{
                        name : "DENDERMONDE",
                        key  : "LOC2"
                    },{
                        name : "WINTAM",
                        key  : "LOC3"
                    }]
            };
            oSlLocationJSON.setData(Location);
            that.getView().byId("slLocation").setModel(oSlLocationJSON);
        },

        resetEverything: function(){
            var that = this;

            oLocations = [];
            aInfo = [];
            counter = 0;

            //reset all layers and texts
            map.removeLayer(groupTotalJourneyLayers);
            map.removeLayer(groupTotalJourneyLines);

            // Reset all input and output
            that.getView().byId("txtLocationInfo").setText("");
            that.getView().byId("txtAssetInfo").setText("");
            that.getView().byId("txtTimestamp").setText("");
            that.getView().byId("slBatch").setSelectedKey("BATCH0");
            that.getView().byId("slLocation").setSelectedKey("LOC0");
            that.getView().byId("slColor").setSelectedKey("COLOR0");
            that.getView().byId("slType").setSelectedKey("TYPE0");
            that.getView().byId("dBeginDate").setValue("");
            that.getView().byId("dEndDate").setValue("");

            // Reset the target of the map
            // This has to be done every time we call this view as for some reason the map reference seems to disappear after routing multiple other views
            if (that.initialized) {
                map.setTarget(that.getView().byId("map_canvas").getDomRef());
            }

            // Clear sources from the total journey
            if (sourceTotalLocations) {
                if(Array.isArray(sourceTotalLocations) && sourceTotalLocations.length >= 1) {
                    sourceTotalLocations.forEach(function(s){
                        s.clear();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know what's wrong with my controller but when I get too many features on my Openlayers map, the screen freezes when loading them and than the map works really slow after being loaded. I barely can do anything, unless I have a small amount of features.

I also implemented clusters, beneath the clusters there are markers which are clickable to access information. I use filters to show the information which is asked for on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new style for each feature.

Instead, create one style and apply it to each feature.

Comment: I've tried this, even when commenting the code still have the same results.